# MySQL: Get orphans in multiple tables

Tags: mysql

We have inherited a nasty database with a TON of orphaned and corrupt data. I'd like to get it cleaned up but I'm having difficulty figuring out exactly how to go about it because the data spans several tables. Basically, we have a lot of transactions that have no associated orders. These transactions need to be deleted as they have no relevant order information and are causing problems with reporting.

**Table: transactions**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+
```

**Table: registrations**

```
+----+----------------+
| id | transaction_id |
+----+----------------+
|  1 |             10 |
|  2 |              9 |
|  3 |              8 |
|  4 |              7 |
|  5 |              6 |
|  6 |              5 |
|  7 |              4 |
|  8 |              3 |
|  9 |              2 |
| 10 |              2 |
+----+----------------+
```

**Table: store_orders**

```
+----------------+
| transaction_id |
+----------------+
|             10 |
|              9 |
|              8 |
|              7 |
|              6 |
|              5 |
|              4 |
|              3 |
|              2 |
|              2 |
+----------------+
```

So, you'll see that we have transactions 1-10 and we have registrations and store orders which both reference the transactions table. You see that transaction ID 1 is not represented in EITHER `registrations` or `store_orders` and therefore is considered an orphan transaction. Some transactions will only have a registration. Some will have only a store order. Some will have both. The goal of this is to eliminate rows from the transactions table that do not have a corresponding entry in either of the other tables.

Comment: Are you asking us for code?

Comment: he is asking for help. Obviously if he knew any basic sql, he would not have taken the time to ask such a nicely written and formatted question

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for help. It has been a long and frustrating several months working with this software and I've reached the point where I can no longer make any headway due to frustration with the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Delete from transactions where transaction_ID IN (
Select ID 
from transactions T
LEFT JOIN registrations R on T.ID = R.Transaction_ID
LEFT JOIN store_orders SO on T.ID = SO.Transaction_ID
WHERE T.Transaction_ID is null and SO.Transaction_ID is null)
```

- You can just run the portion between the ()'s and see what records it would purge.
- you can spot check those results to confirm it's going to do what you expect
- then you can run the whole thing.

This is getting all transactions and only those records having a registration or an order.  It then eliminates those records from the results that have a registration or an order, leaving only those that have neither a registration nor an order. Put another way, only those transactions that have no corresponding entry in registrations or store_orders.

Using this list it then removes from transactions those id's.